# WKWebView implementation still builds after removing WebKit framework import

Tags: xcode, webkit, wkwebview

1. I'm implementing in an existing project a `WKWebview` in a new view controller.

   ```
   @interface myViewController : UIViewController  <WKNavigationDelegate>

   @property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;

   @end
   ```

**First step result** (normal thing to me) : Xcode build raises an error.

2. Then in my project's **Build Phases** > **Link Binary With Libraires** I add `WebKit.framework`, and update my controller's imports :

   ```
   #import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

   @interface myViewController : UIViewController  <WKNavigationDelegate>

   @property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;

   @end
   ```

**Second step result** : The project builds successfully now (I expected no less :-) )

3. I'm then removing `WebKit.framework` from my project, and `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>` too

**Final result** : My project still builds, without `WebKit.framework` and WebKit import this time !

So in the end I don't understand why the project successfully builds now without WebKit framework, after removing it (removed also reference in *Frameworks* project folder)

If someone has an explanation, I'll be glad to read it :-)